# How can I eliminate default space generated by a table tag?

Tags: html, css, html-table

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;}
tr{
  width:100%;
  height: 10%;
  float: left;
}
.col{
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.odd{
  background-color: green;
}
.even{
  background-color: #fff;
}
#rw-one,#rw-three,#rw-five,#rw-seven,#rw-nine{
  /*width: 100%;
  height: 100%;*/
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: red;
}
table{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="rw-one">
    <td class="odd col"> </td>
    <td class="even col"> </td>
    <td class="odd col"> </td>
    <td class="even col"> </td>
    <td class="odd col"> </td>
    <td class="even col"> </td>
    <td class="odd col"> </td>
    <td class="even col"> </td>
    <td class="odd col"> </td>
    <td class="even col"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="rw-two"></tr>
  <tr id="rw-three"></tr>
  <tr id="rw-four"></tr>
  <tr id="rw-five"></tr>
  <tr id="rw-six"></tr>
  <tr id="rw-seven"></tr>
  <tr id="rw-eight"></tr>
  <tr id="rw-nine"></tr>
  <tr id="rw-ten"></tr>
</table>
```

In the above code I'm tried to create a table with 10 rows and on the first row there is 10 columns.the table have a `width:100%;`  and each row have a `height:10%;` and  `height:100%;`.and each row is again divided in to 10 parts (width:10% each).but the 10 columns are didn't fit on the first row .probably generating some default space by  or  tag,how can I fix this?

Comment: try rowspan or colspan attributes

Comment: If you're not using `colspan` all table rows must contain the same of amount of cells.

Comment: "and each row have a `height:10%;` and `height:100%;`" ???

Comment: @conexo in my table all  rows must contain the same of amount of cells ,but i'm just started  to coding and find this bug

Comment: @conexo total height is 100%,i'm divided ,i have 10 rows =>so give each row width:10%;(100/10)

Comment: @conexo really I'm locking for a 10 x 10,but just stopped when find this **bug**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding padding:0 to your .col class.

```
.col{
 padding:0;
 width: 10%;
 height: 100%;
 float: left;
}
```

I think that should work. see this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWwzGQ)

Comment: Great. if you're happy with the answer, don't forget to give it a tick.

Comment: yeah sure...i waiting for that